# When does two functions being almost equal imply their derivatives are also almost equal

Tags: calculus, functions, upper-lower-bounds

I am sorry if this question is vague. Consider two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Their values are almost equal at all points. But their derivatives need not be equal. For example, let $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\sin(10^{15}x)\times10^{-5}$. Then $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq 10^{-5}$ $\forall x$ but $|\frac{df(x)}{dx}-\frac{dg(x)}{dx}|$ could be as large as $10^{10}$. My question is given $|f(x)-g(x)| \lt \delta$ what minimum additional information about these functions does one need that allows to bound  $|\frac{df(x)}{dx}-\frac{dg(x)}{dx}|$.

Comment: As you noticed, there is no way to control $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}-\frac{\mathrm{d}g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}$ using an estimate on $f(x)-g(x)$. For instance, given any two functions $f$ and $g$, one could add a constant $\lambda=g(x)-f(x)$ to f, so that the functions $g$ and $f+\lambda$ would coincide at point $x$, but that wouldn't tell you anything about their derivatives. Obviously, if you control the second derivatives of $f$ and $g$ you can use the mean value theorem but that's going backwards.

Comment: The fact that you've basically shown that the disagreement between the derivatives can be arbitrarily bad makes this a bit of an odd question. I presume you're seeking some kind of regularity condition on the functions, but you haven't given a precise condition you want. Would this be a more-precise version of your question?  "If a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $f(x)$ what conditions imply that $f_n'(x)$ converges uniformly to $f'(x)$?"  Your example generalized would give a counterexample like: $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sin(n x).$

Comment: We can also think of embedding of $W^{2,1}$ into $C^1$, thus to be basic  controlling $||f'||_1$ and $||f''||_1$ gives control over $||f'||_\infty$, but this is already advanced stuff.